# Factorise $x^n+x^{n-1}+...+x+1$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, roots-of-unity

Is there a way to factorise $x^n+x^{n-1}+. . .+x+1$?
I've tried to take the $1$ out, but now I do not know where to go from here because it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hint: $$x^{n+1}-1=(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+\ldots+x+1)$$ And you may want to look at the Argand diagram.

Comment: If $n+1$ is prime, then the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: HINT: $x^{n - 1} = \frac{x^n}{x}$ so for example you have $x^n + x^{n - 1}$, this equals $x^n + \frac{x^n}{x}$. This equals $\frac{x^nx + x^n}{x}$. So $x(x^n + x^{n - 1}) = x^n(x + 1)$

Comment: The question can be expressed as x^(n+1)/(x-1), but I can't go any further.

Comment: @abc... well, if you are working under $\Bbb A$, $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, note that the roots of the polynomial $x^k-1$ form a $k$-polygon in the Argand diagram.

Comment: You have not specified where the coefficients of the factors are to lie. If in $\Bbb R$, then the answer of @Bernard does nicely; if in $\Bbb Q$, the story is entirely different. So please illuminate us, if you would.

Answer (score 8):

**Hints:**

The  roots of this polynomial are the complex $n+1\mkern-1mu$-th roots of unity different from $1$. So, if you set $\zeta=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}{n+1}}$, it factors over $\mathbf C$ as
$$(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)\dots(x-\zeta^k)\dotsm(x-\zeta^n),$$ so all you have to obtain a factorisation over $\mathbf R$ as a product of irreduciblle quadratic polynomials is to group the factors corresponding to conjugate powers of $\zeta$.

You'll have to consider two cases: $n$ odd and $n$ even.